# iOS App distribution model

Tags: ios, model, distribution, b2b

We have an app, which is "only" part of a complete solution. The solution itself is server-based and can be used also via browser, android or windows phone and with a desktop client for mac or windows.

As you can see, iOS os only one possible client. The customers (B2B) have a volume-contract with us, where let's say 400 users are included.

Apple states, because the customer has to pay for the usage of the solution, we should enable the in-App purchase or sell the app (right now it's for free).

Our customers are huge international companies, the don't want to have their employees have to buy the app or an in app purchase to use their package on the ipad.

What would be the best way to have our app delivered for free in the app store and don't have the users to pay within the app for something their contractor is paying for.

Any solution for that ?

Help is appreciated

MadMaxApp

Comment: It's a good question, but probably off topic for SO. FWIW, if there's really a problem here, it seems like it's that you're charging essentially per-user, but denying Apple their cut. If you charged a flat fee for the server and nothing per user you'd probably be on firmer ground.

Comment: Thats what we do, but Apple looked at the website and saw that there is a fee to pay to use the service. That's why they rejected the app and told us to activate the in-App purchase.

Comment: Does the volume-purchase system work in other countries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The customers (B2B) have a volume-contract with us, where let's say 400 users are included.

If I'm not mistaken, you can sell your app through Apple's B2B store, where you can sell in volume. Your client could buy some number of copies of the app and manage those licenses as they like. That at least makes it easier for individual users. Your corporate customers may not be thrilled to pay extra for an iOS client, but at least you can blame Apple.

Comment: "The Volume Purchase Program is currently available in the US only." so this is not an option for us. The Users and the companies using the solution are located worldwide.

Comment: Ok! Today Apple announced that volume purchasing is also released in germany now. This is a good way to go for us!